# Arduino unable to read from XBee Series 2

Tags: programming, serial, sketch, arduino-nano, xbee

An XBee Series 2 is set to `Router AT` whose `TX` and `RX` pins are connected to an Arduino Nano's `Rx` and `Tx` pins respectively. The Arduino is connected to a Mac OSX via USB.

A second XBee Series 2 is connected to a Windows system via USB. It is set to `Coordinator API` mode.

Using the sketch below on the Arduino, a packet is sent from the `Router AT` XBee to the `Coordinator API` XBee, which is seen by `XCTU` as a Explicit RX frame. However the Arduino LED should blink once if it received a reply packet (should it?)

On another test, I wrote a script to send a frame for the `Coordinator API` XBee to send to the `Router AT` XBee. Once again the Arduino LED does not blink, and nothing is seen using Arduino's Serial Monitor.

**Testing the `Coordinator API` XBee**

Using the same script to send a packet from `Coordinator API` XBee to itself, the packet was received as well as a delivery confirmation packet. This shows that both the `Coordinator API` XBee and the script are working.

```
// Delivery confirmation 
received:  { type: 144,
  remote64: '0013a20040a74613',
  remote16: '0000',
  receiveOptions: 1,
  data: [ 116 ] }

// Received the packet sent to itself     
received:  { type: 139,
  id: 1,
  remote16: '0000',
  transmitRetryCount: 0,
  deliveryStatus: 0,
  discoveryStatus: 0 }
```

**Testing the Arduino Sketch Code**

Using the same Arduino sketch which continuously sends API frames to the `Coordinator`, I connected the `Router AT` XBee's `RX` pin to Arduino's `RX` pin, so the frames the Arduino are sending out are going back into its `RX` pin.

This causes the Arduino's LED to light up! So there is nothing wrong with the code.

**Problem:** Does this mean the `Router AT` XBee is not configured properly? I do not think its `TX` pin is damaged because `XCTU` can still read the settings off this XBee. Any ideas on how we can troubleshoot this?

**Arduino Sketch (Connected to Router Xbee)**

```cpp
#include <XBee.h>

XBee xbee = XBee();
uint8_t payload[] = { 0, 0 };

// SH + SL Address of receiving XBee
XBeeAddress64 addr64 = XBeeAddress64(0x0013a200, 0x40a74613);
ZBTxRequest zbTx = ZBTxRequest(addr64, payload, sizeof(payload));
ZBTxStatusResponse txStatus = ZBTxStatusResponse();


void setup() {
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

    Serial.begin(9600);
    xbee.setSerial(Serial);
}



void loop() {
    xbee.send(zbTx);
    delay(1000);

    xbee.readPacket();
    if (xbee.getResponse().isAvailable()) {
        // Response received, blink LED once
        Serial.println('resposne!');
        digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
        delay(1000);
        digitalWrite(13, LOW);
        delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused about how you're sending the `Router AT` packet to the `Coordinator` in `API` mode. Sending out via AT is a `Serial.print("sample");`. Whereas the sketch you have above only shows us the Coordinator's outwards bound packet. Does that library handle `AT` mode as well? And what about addresses? You don't need to explicitly set the address outwards of the Coordinator (although it wouldn't hurt), the Coordinator should/can broadcast it's message. Can you confirm the `ATDL` of the Router is `0x0` or `0xFFFF` if ATDH is `0x0`.

Comment: Just as another afterthought, do put the pertinent XBee settings in the post to confirm you've got it right.  Copy them from the digi software. I just confirmed from https://code.google.com/p/xbee-arduino/ that the library doesn't work in AT mode. Also, it does require `ATAP=2` so that's something else to check.

Comment: @Madivad I'm so sorry, the arduino code is for `Router AT` Xbee, not `Coordinator` XBee. Made the change in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments to your question, if you are using [this](https://code.google.com/p/xbee-arduino/) library
then it doesn't actually support AT mode. In fact, AT mode (otherwise known as Transparent Mode) is simply attached to the `Serial` port and accessed directly through the `Serial` object.

Example: put this into your Arduino attached to the AT Router.

```
#define LED 13

void setup() {
    pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("\nXBee AT communications test");
}

void loop() {
  static unsigned long previous = millis()/1000;
  if(previous != millis()/1000){
    previous = millis()/1000;
    char buffer[5];    
    sprintf(buffer,"%04i",previous);
    Serial.println(buffer);
   digitalWrite(LED, !digitalRead(LED)); 
  }
}
```

Then open the console on the XCTU software on the API Coordinator watch the packets.

[image: look at packet 0102]

You will see above the received packets from the router. Because the coordinator is in `API` mode, you see it like this. (In `AT` mode, you will see the raw packets.

Ichose numbers to send because they are easy to read in this form. Packet `0102` appears in the packets data as `30 31 30 32 0D 0A`

In `AT` mode there is no packet confirmation, validations, status or anything. They are all handled "transparently".

As a side note, I've seen many references that both XBees need to be in the same mode. That is, in fact, incorrect. If we modify our source to include `Serial.read` you would see data the other way as well.

**edit:** I thought I would add communications between `AT Router` and `API Coordinator`. I have modified the code in the `Router` to receive a constructed packet from the `Coordinator` via the XCTU software.

```
#define LED 13

boolean serialComplete = false;
char bufferIn[64];
char bufferOut[5];
int count=0;

void setup() {
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("\nXBee AT communications test");
}

void loop() {
  static unsigned long previous = millis()/1000;
  if(serialComplete) {
    Serial.println(bufferIn);
    serialComplete=false;
    count = 0;
    memset(bufferIn,0,sizeof(bufferIn));
    digitalWrite(LED,!digitalRead(LED)); 
  }
  if(previous != millis()/1000){
    previous = millis()/1000;
    sprintf(bufferOut,"%04u",(uint16_t)previous);
    Serial.println(bufferOut);
  }
}

void serialEvent() {
  while (Serial.available()) {
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read(); 
    if (inChar == '\n' || inChar == '\0') {
      bufferIn[count++]=0;
      serialComplete = true;
    } else {
      bufferIn[count++] = inChar;
    }
  }
}
```

Then in XCTU construct a packet for the `Coordinator`. I'm using version 6.1.0.

[image: add API frame]

and click "the create frame using form generator tool"

[image: form generator tool]

here is the packet being received by the router. I am only sending `9999` `nul` terminated.

[image: result]

Then once the pair are running, you can send the constructed packet from the XCTU software and it will be received by the router.

Answer (score 1):

`#include <XBee.h>
uint8_t text[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o',' ','T','H','I','S',' ','I','S',' ', 'A','R','D','U','I','N','O'};
XBee xbee = XBee();
XBeeAddress64 remoteAddress = XBeeAddress64(0x00000000, 0x0000FFFF);//64 address of remote xbee:
ZBTxRequest zbTx = ZBTxRequest(remoteAddress, text, sizeof(text));// api 2 Tx request frame
ZBRxResponse zbRx = ZBRxResponse();// reading remote xbee response:
void setup()
      {
        Serial.begin(9600);
        xbee.setSerial(Serial);
        Serial.println("starting up yo!");
      }
void loop ()
      {

         xbee.readPacket();// This will read any data that is available:
         if (xbee.getResponse().isAvailable())//Now, to check if a packet was received: 
          {

            if (xbee.getResponse().getApiId() == ZB_RX_RESPONSE) 
              {
                xbee.send(zbTx);//sending data to remote xbee:
              }
          }
      }`